# JSP hit counter with cookies

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies, counter

Im working on a school project, that contains a hit counter with using cookies. I used to make counters just passing an incrementing value into variables in beans at every refresh, but I've been told, that this is bad solution. 
The specifications for this tasks are clear :

- create a hit counter
- use a cookie to do this
- set expiration date of cookie

Is there somebody with a solution ? Im getting pretty clueless about it..

Thanks for each helpful answer.

Comment: What is the problem ? Don't you know to create cookie or don't know to set the expiration date ?

Comment: I dont know how to use a cookie to make a hit counter. (But i know how to create it and set expiration.) Trying to figure out how to use them to count visitors ...

Comment: you will not get the ready made solution here. Here we can help in solving your errors,exceptions etc

Comment: @NullpointerExceptionBuster : You can improvise on the code which I have posted , go through it and the Javadoc.

Comment: @Aniket : Im not asking or searching a ready made solution, I was just asking for inspiration, for pointing me at right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below in your `doXXX()` method :

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
int count = 0;
for(Cookie cookie:cookies){
    if(cookie.getName().equals("www.yourDomain.com.HitCounter")){
        count = Integer.parseInt(cookie.getValue());
        count++;
        cookie.setValue(count+"");
    }
}
if(count == 0){
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("www.yourDomain.com.HitCounter","1");
    cookie.setMaxAge(3600*10*24);// expire in 10 days.
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

To know about cookies in Servlets , please visit the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html).

Comment: Thanks :) But isnt the expiration set on 10 hours ? (3600 secs - 1 hr)

Comment: Yes , that was typo ..